# Bolding text not working consistently between preview and final

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, markdown-rendering

I noticed that if I bold something and it is not surrounded by white space it does not bold in the final text. Though it does bold in the preview while I am editing.

What I typed:

`(**$**C2)`

[image]

Which in the preview immediately below looks like this

[image]

But when I hit save and the question is re-rendered the formatting isn't applied and it looks like this

[image]

I can add some white space (`**$** C2`) and then it will bold but that's not really what I wanted

[image]

Comment: this seem related on the uber meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192875/why-intra-word-highlighting-is-broken-to-protect-programming-underscore-usage and is status-declined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use html markup:

(**$**C2)

> `(<b>$</b>C2)`

as I believe this is a quirk in the server side Markdown processor that will not be fixed, based on [Why intra-word ** highlighting is broken to protect programming_underscore_usage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192875/why-intra-word-highlighting-is-broken-to-protect-programming-underscore-usage)

Comment: huh, I see some comments on there saying that the reason the preview pane is able to render how I would expect is because it uses a different markdown processor. The HTML seems like a fine workaround but it's still unexpected behavior for them to render two different things.

Comment: @Brad: One is client-side and the other is server-side. There's bound to be implementation disparities. Ideally one would use a client-side and server-side renderer that's either branched off the same codebase or are direct ports of one another, rather than two independent implementations.